# How to change Data Tier(Sql Instance) in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have just installed TFS Server 2010 but during installation I selected SqlExpress as my data tier. Both my TFS application server and database exists on the same box. I also have full enterprise Sql Server edition on the samebox and now want to use the same rather than SqlExpress.

In TFS administration console, I found no way to change my data tier. I haven't created any project as such on TFS so there is no data to migrate. I just want to use my default instance now.
How to go about this ?

Comment: Not sure why this was voted as off topic.  These tfs questions are traditionally supported on SO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At this early point, you might as well just uninstall and reinstall.  That's probably the easiest method.

Comment: is there a better than uninstall.What if i need to migrate it to different instance in future with data in it.

Comment: I believe the installation process also provides a way to migrate to a new instance.  I don't have the installer available to me at the moment, so I can't check.  Try re-running the installer and see what options it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

FROM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.120).aspx
In order to restore the TFS databases using the restore tool, you must install but not configure TFS on the new data-tier server, and then use the restore function in the Scheduled Backups node.

Install TFS and cancel the setup TFS setup window once it opens.  Or in my case I used the Uninstall Application tier option in the TFS Admin Tool. I didn't know you could cancel the application tier install. The wizard kind of forces you into it. Then I had to rename\delete the configuration db and any others that were created in the install.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this today for a TFS 2018 and found the below article useful. May not fit everyone's scenario but sharing since this SO link came on top of search results.

Run

> TfsRestore.exe

in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools`
folder. It has a GUI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/jj620932(v=vs.110)